# bash expect how to save respond output to a variable during the ssh connection

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, expect

i ssh into a machine. and i do a send command. I want to capture all those output to a variable.

I tried

```
output=$(send "rpm -i mypkg.rpm\r")
```

But it doesnt work. any idea?

Error Message

```
")": no such variablean't read "(send ""rpm -i mypkg.rpm
while executing
"output=$(send "rpm -i mypkg.rpm\r")"
```

Comment: Is the space after the equal sign in your actual code? If yes, remove it. It should be `output=$( ...` with no spaces

Comment: thanks , but not this problem

Comment: What shell is the remote machine running? It looks like it does not recognize `$(...)` as a command substitution, and it is processing the `\r` as a carriage return, resulting in the garbled-looking error message.

Answer (score 1):

As [already stated by user000001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725397/bash-expect-how-to-save-respond-output-to-a-variable-during-the-ssh-connection#comment27594217_18725397), you have a space character after `=` which does not work in bash, because bash will interpret it as a command with parameters.
But what is the point of capturing the command output inside ssh session? Most probably you want it from your client machine, so here is the code:

```
output=$(ssh myhost 'rpm -i mypkg.rpm')
```

Some programs will freak out if you're executing them this way, that's because there is no terminal. You can force pseudo-tty allocation by using `-t` flag with ssh.

#### You have updated your question:

`"output=$(send "rpm -i mypkg.rpm\r")"` - The problem here is your quoting. You can solve that by mixing different types of quotes. For example:

```
"output=$(send 'rpm -i mypkg.rpm\r')"
```

Comment: @runcode I have updated my answer, but please, show us your real code, currently I have no extrasensory perception to guess what the problem might be :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of creating variables in `Expect` is for example:
`set output "some content"`

To set the variable `output` with the last command run you can do:

```
send "rpm -i mypkg.rpm\r"          // send the command
expect '#'                         // wait for the prompt
set output $expect_out(buffer);    // store the output in 'output' variable
```

I don't think that `Bash` syntax will work here ( `output=$( command )`